# slide li from right to left using easing

Tags: jquery, slider, bxslider, jquery-ui-slider

i want to slide li from right to left and vice versa.

```
<div class="viewCont" style="width: 200px;">

  <ul class="slider">
    <li class="slide">one</li>
    <li class="slide">two</li>
    <li class="slide">three</li>
    <li class="slide">four</li>
  </ul>

 <div class="prev btn">Prev</div>
 <div class="next btn">Next</div>

</div>
```

i found some code in javascript but all of them are very long. can anyone provide me some short code in jquery.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything ? This is not a free service for writing code.

Comment: yes i know,  i tried answer of this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387929/slide-content-from-right-to-left-using-jquery

Comment: but as i said script is too complex there, i want to do something like, https://www.homehero.org/care-finder/needs?href=lander